# Select .xps file from google drive

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api, uidocumentpickervc

I want to select .xps file from google drive using document picker but file shows unable to select.
I am able to select this file from iCloud without any changes but not from google drive.

I don't want to use google drive SDK.

I have tried this code.

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController *picker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[(NSString*)kUTTypeItem,(NSString *)kUTTypeContent] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
picker.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: you mean it's not showing in the picker UI?

Comment: .xps file show in picker but can't able to select. because it is disable.